# gawk64 command trobleshooting

Tags: gawk

I am trying to trouble shoot an awk script and having trouble with the gawk64 command.

*gawk64 -f awkmakearchive.txt -v SPD=abc.csv -v REF=def.csv ijk.csv*

In the awkmakearchive.txt file i am getting syntax error for the following 
line :

```
BEGIN {

FS = ","

# Load SPD
spdcount = 0
while (getline < SPD) {
    for (i=0; i<96; i++) {
        Pattern[$1][i] = $(i+2) ----> Syntax error
    }
    spdcount++
}
....
...
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Rather than just saying you got "a sytnax error", if tell us the actual error message and then we much stand a better chance of being able to tell you what that message means. FWIW my money is on it being you using an awk version that pre-dates the multi-dimensional array syntax you're using.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for taking the time to go through this problem. You are right! i was using GnuWin32 to run the script instead of GnuWin  64 bit version. GnuWin32 did not have gawk64 in its bin.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I was using GnuWin32 to run the script instead of GnuWin  64 bit version. GnuWin32 did not have gawk64 in its bin.